# 2003 Hyundai Tiburon overheating

Tags: hyundai, overheating, tiburon

I recently bought a 2003 Hyundai tiburon. It keeps overheating after running for about 5 minutes.

I took it to my local Hyundai dealership and they concluded the reason was bc the radiator was leaking and the fans weren’t turning on. Long story short I ran my own wiring and what not so I can turn on the fans with a switch.Regardless, that doesn’t work. It’s still overheating.

The guy I bought the car from said the water pump needed to be replaced and I couldn’t do it myself. So I got the mechanics to do it and still it over heats. Then I remembered that the radiator was leaking badly so I also replaced that myself and it still continues to overheat. Just today I thought of replacing the thermometer thing in it but that didn’t help either.

I’m truly lost ah what to do now because I really need a running car, this one does blow hot air out the vents. The radiator blows cold to warmish air while the engine overheats. I can’t sell the car bc I tried and no one seemed interested with this car. If you have any ideas for help please let me know.

Comment: have you checked the pipes for blockages?

Comment: Did you completely evacuate (burp) the coolant system of air?

Comment: At 17 years old it's quite possible that the radiator hoses are failing.  Often the inner liner of the hose collapses and blocks the flow.  Check both the upper and the lower hoses.

Comment: Next time you visit the mechanic or the dealer tell them you want the overheating problem solved, don't tell them what part you want replaced. Because they will. Now you've replaced all relevant parts, radiator, thermostat, water pump, fans wired in. What's left? Clogged coolant passages in the head or block?